# Nested Loops Join happens twice when using index

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I'm using oracle and have a question about Nested Loops Join execution plan.

When I tried to Nested Loops Join COURSE table and PROFESSOR table, it happened twice.

Before joining those two tables, I made the two tables index scan.

I think the index scan generated NL Join.

I want to make NL Join happen just one time.

```
(1. index scan with COURSE table

 2. index scan with PROFESSOR table

 3. NL Join just one time)
```

If you answer this question, I really appreciate that.

[image: QUERY]

[image: EXECUTION PLAN]

Comment: You cannot avoid second NL, because after first one you'll get only rowids of the required rows, not the information requested (since `b.pname` not in index)

Comment: Also, please learn to how to write ansi join syntax. The join syntax you are using has been considered outdated and bad practice for decades

Comment: The `nlj_batching` hint was applied to your query. See https://dioncho.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/batching-nlj-optimization-and-ordering/